# Module not found error (JavaFX) -- running a cloned repo on my Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle, javafx

Please help.  I am trying to run an app that is cloned from a GitHub repository. I could run it fine from the terminal (with `./gradlew run` (I'm using MacOS)), but if I open the project in Eclipse and run it from there, it fails. (My goal is not just to run the app on my computer but to run it from Eclipse so that I could add a feature or two in the future for personal use).

I searched for solutions all day and tried different things, but solving one error led to another.

What I've done in detail:

1. Open the project from "Open Projects from File System.."
2. Right click on the project and "Configure" -> "Add Gradle Nature" (Not sure if this is the right step to take)
3. Right click on project -> build path -> library -> move the "project and external dependencies" library (includes all jar files such as javafx-controls-17-mac.jar) from classpath to modulepath (This step gets rid of all errors except one within the src/test/java folder, which I believe does not directly affect running the app).

If I run the app I get the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found
```

I tried adding

```
--module-path /Users/julie/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.openjfx/javafx-controls--add-modules javafx.controls
```

under VM Arguments in Run Configurations but it would give me this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class javafx.controls
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.controls
```

The path is what I found by looking at "project and external dependencies" library that came with the code (provided by the author). Not sure if that's the right way to do it, but I thought it makes sense to use something within the cloned repo rather than downloading a new javafx and use that path.

I've tried many more things for 8+ hrs.. I don't recall all of them but here are some different error messages I got:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
    java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: . . .


module-info 2.class found in top-level directory
```

I think the last error has to do with creating second `.class` files in bin folder.. I don't know what's causing it but I had to delete all duplicate `.class` files manually many times. (If somebody can tell me why this is happening, it will be greatly appreciated...)

I've never used Gradle nor JavaFX in my life so this might be a dumb question but please help me out.

FYI, the repo I cloned is
https://github.com/mfl28/BoundingBoxEditor.git

Comment: Go to openjfx.io and follow the getting started documentation for a hello world app.  Just do exactly what it says there and nothing else.

Comment: I looked at the linked git repo, it looks like a really cool project, but if you have zero JavaFX experience, starting with trying to make modifications to that project is not really recommended IMO, instead I advise working through tutorials like the makery tutorial.

Comment: @jewelsea I did follow the instructions for a hello world app and launched it without a problem, but I still can't get this project to work on my machine. I understand your concern but I'm afraid I won't have enough time for working through makery tutorials...

Comment: I don't use Eclipse so I can't help you with that.  I did clone the repository and load it into Idea 2022.1.4 using FIle | New Project from Version Control on OS X 12.4.  I used  JDK 11 for the project JDK (the project uses [Gradle 6.5 which is only compatible with JDK 14 and lower](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html)).  I ran a Gradle build on the project and it built fine and auto-launched a bunch of TestFX tests, 29 out of 30 of those worked (I think failed test may have required a screen recording option enabled for the app in the OS preferences).

Comment: To get the build to work I had to comment out in the build.gradle the plugin `com.github.hierynomus.license` and the `license {` block as those reported failures which blocked the build.

Comment: @jewelsea I tought I would be able to get away with not using this app but I'd have to.... So I just tried it out again on IntelliJ and it would build fine and pass all the tests. However, if I try to run BoundingBoxEditorApp as a java application (right clicking and clicking on green triangle) I'd get: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
The jdk is set as 11 on the IntelliJ(since it's one of the things that I should check based on other stackoverflow post).

Comment: Sorry, I cannot  tell you why the execution fails for you, given the information that you have provided.